# How to get website URLs from a sentence?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I need to identify URLs (links) in a sentence using C#.Net Windows Form's TextBox.

e.g.: `That is http://stackoverflow.com link.`

that sentence is in the textbox.

I need to extract `http://stackoverflow.com` from this sentence.

How can i do that ?

Thanks you for your time.

Comment: Try to improve your access rate.

Answer (score 3):

Look up hyperlink regular expression - you can this plug in what you find into a `Regex` object and it will capture the url for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = "That is my url expression http://stackoverflow.com ";    
string pattern = @"((https?|http):((//)|(\\\\))+[\w\d:#@%/;$()~_?\+-=\\\.&]*)";    
string[] arr = Regex.Split(str, pattern); Console.WriteLine(arr[1]);
```

Comment: Very Thanks you.
Your Answer is very suitable for my problem.
Please give him point. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LinkLabel` control. Provide text to the `Text` attribute and then in the proerty `LinkArea` define where only should be link. The only thing is that only one link per full `LinkLabel` text allowed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
detail = Core.URL.Replace(detail, 
      delegate(Match match)
      {
          // match.ToString() will contain http://stackoverflow.com in your case :)
          return string.Format("<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"{0}\">{0}</a>", match.ToString());
      });
```

With `Core.URL.Replace` defined as:

```
public static Regex URL = new Regex(@"(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

This code originally came from:

http://weblogs.asp.net/farazshahkhan/archive/2008/08/09/regex-to-find-url-within-text-and-make-them-as-link.aspx#7224581

Comment: No brother.Below answer is correct for my problem.
But very thank you for your hardworking. :)